# regex negative look-ahead in ruby 1.9.3 vs 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-negation

I need to match members of an array that end with `"bar"` but do not start with `"foo"`, and put the result in a new array.

Looking at the docs for 1.9.3 and 2.0.0, they seem to support negative look-ahead with the same syntax. Negative look-ahead works as I expect in ruby 2.0.0 but doesn't seem to work in ruby 1.9.3:

```
["foo a.bar", "b.bar"].grep(/(?!^foo\s).*\.bar$/)
# => ["b.bar"]              (ruby 2.0.0)
# => ["foo a.bar", "b.bar"] (ruby 1.9.3)
```

The ruby version on this infrastructure will be upgraded in 4 months, but changing the version sooner isn't an option. How can I make this work in 1.9.3 and preferably continue to work in 2.0?

Comment: I think this is Ruby 2.0's bug rather than Ruby 1.9.3's.

Comment: I just reported this bug to [Ruby Core](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9728).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better use this, which looks more convincing:

```
matched = array.grep(/^(?!foo\s).*\.bar$/)
```

`NOT` starting with foo

this will work in both 2.1.1 and 1.9.3

only if you want to see what I did:

```
# ruby-1.9.3-p362
array = ["foo a.bar", "b.bar"] 
# => ["foo a.bar", "b.bar"] 
matched = array.grep(/(?!^foo\s).*\.bar$/)
# => ["foo a.bar", "b.bar"] 
matched = array.grep(/^(?!foo\s).*\.bar$/)
# => ["b.bar"] 
matched = array.grep(/(?!^foo\s).*\.bar$/)
# => ["foo a.bar", "b.bar"]

# ruby-2.1.1
array = ["foo a.bar", "b.bar"] 
# => ["foo a.bar", "b.bar"] 
matched = array.grep(/(?!^foo\s).*\.bar$/)
# => ["b.bar"] 
matched = array.grep(/^(?!foo\s).*\.bar$/)
# => ["b.bar"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution would be not to use negative look-ahead, if it seems problematic in ruby version you are bound to on production servers. If your example is particular enough you could use `select` and convenient String methods:

```
array.select {|str| !str.starts_with?('foo') && str.ends_with?('bar') }
```

Comment: I would also expect this to be faster (especially if you optimise to have lowest-frequency match first). Although OP may have simplified the question and in reality have pattern-matches instead of "foo" and "bar".

Answer (score 3):

It's your regex that's faulty, not Ruby.  Ruby 2 seems to be a little more forgiving, is all.

The start anchor (`^`) should be *before* the lookahead, not in it.  When it fails to match `foo` at the beginning of the line, the regex engine bumps forward one position and tries again.  It's not at the start of the string any more, so `^` doesn't match, the negative lookahead reports success, and the regex matches `oo a.bar`.  (This is a very common mistake.)

Comment: I think you are right, and that Ruby 2.0 is wrong rather than Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: Genius explanation on why this fails too!